# How to guess browser compatibility based upon DOM Level?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser

Is there a simple rule-of-thumb to know approximately which browser versions and upward will be compatible with a given DOM level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use feature detection:

- DOM-Events Level 2: document.implementation.hasFeature("Events",
  "2.0")
- DOM-Core Level 2:
  document.implementation.hasFeature("Core", "2.0"))
- DOM-XPath Level 3:
  document.implementation.hasFeature("XPath", "3.0")

Camp 1: Gecko (Firefox, Mozilla), WebKit (Safari, Chrome), Presto-based (Opera) browsers support DOM Core/Events/XPath Level 2, some of them support Level 3.0

Camp 2: Trident-based (Internet Explorer) support DOM Level 0 (which is not a standard)

Hope this helps.

Worth noticing, there is [Ample SDK](http://www.amplesdk.com/) Ajax GUI framework that enables DOM Level 2/3 in Internet Explorer as well as in other browsers by re-implementing it.

Comment: I think you mean Trident-based for Internet Explorer?

Comment: hasFeature is obsolete and will be deprecated according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/hasFeature . More information in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317691/why-document-implementation-hasfeature-always-return-true#43317742