# Why document.implementation.hasFeature() always return true?

Tags: javascript, dom

I found a weird problem: whatever parameters passed to the hasFeature function, it always returns true.

```js
console.log(document.implementation.hasFeature('HTML', '2.0'));//return true
console.log(document.implementation.hasFeature('fake', '9.0'));//return true
```

Can anyone pls tell me why the hasFeature() function does not work properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From MDN: [`DOMImplementation.hasFeature()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/hasFeature)

> The `DOMImplementation.hasFeature()` method returns a Boolean flag indicating if a given feature is supported. It is deprecated and modern browsers return true in all cases.
>
> The different implementations fairly diverged in what kind of features were reported. The latest version of the spec settled to force this method to always return true, where the functionality was accurate and in use.

Comment: thx. I ran some code in IE 8 and confirmed that hasFeature() worked properly. So it still works for some older browsers. BTW, according to the book _Professional JavaScript for Web Developer the third edition_, in most cases, it’s a good idea to
use capability detection in addition to hasFeature() before using specific parts of the DOM.

Comment: All those description are correct only for modern browsers. Older browsers behave the expected way.